# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() | PySimpleGUI | MacOS

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am coding a PySimple GUI script and I keep getting this:

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

(clipping of code)

```
window = sg.Window('Pico Ducky Script Manager', layout, size=(950, 350)) #950, 170

while True:
  event, values = window.read()
```

full code here:
https://github.com/p-i-c-o/Pico-Ducky-Script-Manager/blob/main/new.py

I did some research and it seems the Window var. is empty so it gives me the error, but I've got no clue on how to fix it

When it runs, it starts in my app bar, then it dissapears.

Comment: Full exception information, please.

Comment: Wow... lots of code... really old PySimpleGUI calls...would be helpful to get much more details... and perhaps ask on  PSG GitHub.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.